# Check if cell is not empty and copy a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to ask for some help. My purpose is to check if DR108 cell is empty (or have "-" in it, in order to avoid hidden 0, the sheet deals with soccer scores, i can replace to it if it is better) and if the condition is false, (it has a number in it), then copy the DN108:DS108 range to the DT108 range. I've tried a couple of ways (isempty, if not isempty, <> ""), searched on the forums but still didn't found the correct answer for me I always got mainly 2 error messages: error 9 and error 1004. Can you help me to do this?

Bonus Question: How can i loop the command in the range of DR108:DR183 in order to avoid the coding every line? I've read about offset(1) command but my VBA knowledge is really poor and I am struggling every time I need to do something.Thank you very much.

```
Dim cel as String
Set cel = Range("DR108").Value  
If cel <> "" Then  
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("DN108:DS108")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("DT108").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

Else 

Return

End If
```

Comment: Hint: use the `IsEmpty()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will loop trough 108 to 183 and test if cell value is anything else than empty. If yes, then it will copy contents to respective row in column DT as values (it ignores formatting) otherwise it skips to another cell in range.

```
Sub simple_IF_copy()
    Dim n As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turns off screen updating, makes macro go faster

For n = 108 To 183 'range for which macro should do the loop
    If Range("DR" & n).Value <> "" Then 'checks cells DR108 to DR183 for values
        Range("DN" & n, "DS" & n).Copy ' Copy of range DN:DS
        Range("DT" & n).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'pastes values in DT in the same row
        Else:
    End If
Next n

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pawel! However somehow it doesn't start to me... Since I have to insert to my looping macro I can't check it alone, but I pasted everything as you wrote, except the Sub / End sub lines.. 

The macro runs, till the end, the loops are valid, except the newly added lines.

I don't understand because what you gave me seems a well defined answer to my problem, thank you anyway :)

Comment: Just for the better understanding the macro consists of 3 parts:  
1. grabs data from another sheet and pastes into the acivesheet. Later it copies the refreshed datas into another excel file.  

2. copy pastes some ranges for refreshing datas to other ranges  

3. the part you wrote me. The principle is to watch the last 5 match results the team played at home/away etc. If the team doesn't played in that round, it has to skip in order to have the last results. When everything is refreshed the part 1 copy to another workbook comes in.  

so part 1 and 2 goes well, but 3 does nothing

Comment: In order to check if it works, remove/comment out: Application.ScreenUpdating = False and in VBA window cycle trough it using F8 (step by step).
The macro I posted, works within active sheet, make sure that you activate the sheet that contains populated ranges. Otherwise it will loop trough whatever it finds in DR108:DR183 whether it's empty cell or not and this might seem like it does nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly! huge thumbs up! :)